# pass QueryString Paramaters from API Gateway to AWS Lambda c#

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

i am trying to call AWS Lambda using APIGateway and it returns HTML Code. it works fine when i dont pass any parameters, but i want to pass some QueryString parameters and use them in Lambda. i have my Lambda in C# and i see parameters being passed from API

[response from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZDC0.png)
`"headers": {},
  "QueryStringParameters": {
    "Environment": "xzc"
  },
  "PathParameters": {}
}`

In Lambda, the APIGatewayProxyRequest is coming as null
[API Lambda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZiXi.png)
`public string FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)`

how do i read the querystring parameters in AWS Lambda in C#

Comment: Have you looked at this similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283289/how-do-i-map-aws-api-gateway-query-string-to-c-sharp-aws-lambda-function

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just need to check **Use Lambda Proxy integration** in **Integration Request** in your API Gateway resource config.

also

you should include:

```
using Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents;
```

and your handler function header should like something like this:

`public APIGatewayProxyResponse FunctionHandler( APIGatewayProxyRequest input, ILambdaContext context)`

then you can access your query string parameters with:

`input.QueryStringParameters`

Answer (score 1):

Explaining for more than 1 input parameters as sometimes that is also a problem to developers:

**Step 01**: This should be your C-Sharp method

```
public string FunctionHandler(string strEnvironmentA, string strEnvironmentB, ILambdaContext context);
```

**Step 02**: In API > GET Method Execution > Method Request add query string parameter for

- strEnvironmentA
- strEnvironmentB

**Step 03**: In API > GET Method Execution > Integration Request > Body Mapping Template add this application/json template

```
"$input.params('strEnvironmentA')" 
"$input.params('strEnvironmentB')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
public string FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context);
```

And then you can pass the input in the request body instead of query string params.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (request.QueryStringParameters != null)
{
    queryStringParameters = request.QueryStringParameters;
    foreach (var item in queryStringParameters)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"QueryStringParameter - " + item.Key + ":" + item.Value);
    }
}
```